# Backend methods to render html content

Tags: php, node.js, http, backend

I'm looking for insight as to what I should learn for backend development.

My goal is to

- Allow a user to enter content into forms; post that content onto the website
- make this content a part of the site (like twitter, they allow users to make tweets and keep it on their site)
- allow a login/signup

I have tried node.js/express so far. I haven't found anything relating to server side html rendering. PHP seems rather obscure. There are little to no resources there.

Comment: Node and Express can absolutely render HTML server side. It's a core feature to send back text. PHP is probably still literally the most popular language for doing this. Any other choice will likely also be good enough.

Comment: @Evert how do you render html server side then? I'm having trouble there. Apologies for the ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

you can try use micro framework like as [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/) + [Doctrine ORM](https://www.doctrine-project.org/)(or RedBean) for models